# Want to Know the time complexity of below two solution [enhanced - for loop solution vs for loop solution]

Tags: java, foreach, time-complexity

**Question:**
Input:
**accounts** = [[1,5],[7,3],[3,5]]
Output: 10

- Explanation:

1. 1st customer has wealth = 6
2. 2nd customer has wealth = 10
3. 3rd customer has wealth = 8

The 2nd customer is the richest with a wealth of 10.
**
**Below is the solution with for-loop**

```
public int maximumWealth(int[][] accounts) {
    int total_count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < accounts.length; j++) {
        int temp_count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < accounts[0].length; i++) {
            temp_count = accounts[j][i] + temp_count;
            System.out.println(accounts[j][i]);
            System.out.println("value of temp_count" + temp_count);
        }
        if (temp_count > total_count) {
            total_count = temp_count;
            System.out.println("value of total_count" + total_count)
        }
    }
    return total_count;
}
```

**Below is the solution with enhanced for loop**

```
class Solution {
    public int maximumWealth(int[][] accounts) {
        int total_count = 0;
        for (int[] account: accounts) {
            int temp_count = 0;
            for (int item: account) {
                temp_count = item + temp_count;
            }
            if (temp_count > total_count) {
                total_count = temp_count;
            }
        }
        return total_count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would these two have a different time complexity? It's the same operation - two nested loops over a 2D array. They'd both be `O(n*m)`

Answer (score 0):

Both forms of for loop will have same time complexity i.e, O(n*m). The enhanced for loop was introduced in as a simpler way to iterate through all the elements of a Collection . It can also be used for arrays, but this is not the original purpose. Enhanced for loops are simple but inflexible. The word 'Enhanced' doesn't mean that that enhanced for loop is enhanced in terms of time complexity. It's just the same as for loop.